# Bubbling events in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

all 
      Now I defined a change click for checkbox,when chexkbox checked,I will show a tips,I also defined click in my HTML ,when I click everywhere,I will hide a tips,but my problem is When I checked the checkbox,the tips is not show in IE,I 
through debugger，I find the Body click is Trigger，is it a Bubbling events？I try write

```js
window.event ? window.event.cancelBubble = true : e.stopPropagation();
```

,but it is not work,body click still Trigger in IE,in Google isn’t have this problem,how to deal with it?

```js
$(document).on("change", ".checked", function (self) {
   $(".circle_bot").show();
   window.event ? window.event.cancelBubble = true : e.stopPropagation();
}
               
$("body").click(function () {
        $(".circle_bot").hide();
    });
```

```html
<body>
  ...
  <div class="circle_bot"></div>
  ...
<input type="checkbox" class="checked"/>
</body>
```

I want to only trigger check click，isn't trigger body click when chenced the checkbox.

Comment: Please show all relevant code as per [mcve]

Comment: hi,I write my code up,thanks for your look,is there have any solutions to deal with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check what target of click was and do something like:

```
$("body").click(function(event) {
  // don't do anything if checkbox clicked
  if (!$(event.target).is('.checked')) {
    $(".circle_bot").hide();
  }
});
```

note that jQuery provides `event` object in all event handlers so you don't have to see if `window.event` is available, it is done for you